# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: After adding Gson dependency and facebook sdk dependency

Tags: android, facebook, gradle, facebook-sdk-4.0, gson

build.gradle

```
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.12.1'
```

but after adding this it gives me

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:

*I am not adding or removing any code but still error is there*

here is my log cat

```
06-08 13:48:28.022 29087-29087/com.psl.ipune E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                               java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.psl.ipune.ui.fragments.NearByFragment$1
                                                                   at com.psl.ipune.ui.fragments.NearByFragment.<init>(NearByFragment.java:104)
                                                                   at com.psl.ipune.util.AppUtility.<clinit>(AppUtility.java:63)
                                                                   at com.psl.ipune.location.GetLocationService.onStart(GetLocationService.java:74)
                                                                   at android.app.IntentService.onStartCommand(IntentService.java:130)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2833)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2000(ActivityThread.java:159)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1419)
                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
                                                                   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

If I remove any one then it works fine.

> But I want to use both how to handle this issue .

Comment: Add multiDexEnabled = true in your default Config

Comment: yes its already there

Comment: Does clean build succeeds

Comment: yes . clean build succeeds

Comment: After removing `   compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.6.0'` its working, I dont know whats is the problem, How to fix this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i tryed to find for you a solution but, its works for me.
Try to add `mavenCentral()` to the `repositories`:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

and then try to compile with:

```
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
```

i know that the versions are different but that what the Android Studio found for me

Comment: no need to add mavenCentral(), after adding this dependencies its working and again changing to previous also now working fine, Its actually weird, do you have any idea?

Comment: I don't know, but if it's working who cares right?!. maybe the new Android Studio instant running didn't show you updated app.  good luck

Answer (score 0):

I think you're having a dependencies conflict from your terminal pane in android studio do ./gradlew dependencies or gradlew dependencies for windows find the conflict library then you can exclude that dependency

like:

```
compile(com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.6.0){
    exclude group: 'com.google.code.gson', module: 'gson'
}
```

or something along those lines.

Comment: I reread the error it's a fragment library issue. so.. try this for me
compile(com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.6.0){
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
}
The facebook library is using support-v4 version 20.0.x according to maven central but you may using a considerly newer version of support-v4